# Hazelcast and the need for custom serializers; works when creating the server but not when connecting to existing

Tags: hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast to store stuff in distributed maps. We are having a problem with remote servers and I need some feedback on what we can do to resolve the issue.

### We create the server - WORKS

We create a new server (`Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance`) inside our application's JVM. The hazelcast `Config` object we pass in has a bunch of custom serializers defined for all the types we are going to put in the maps. Our objects are a mixture of Protobufs, plain java objects, and a combination of the two. The server starts, we can put objects in the map and get objects back out later. We recently decided to start running Hazelcast in its own dedicated server so we tried the scenario below.

### Server already exists externally, we connect as a client - DOESN'T WORK

Rather than creating our Hazelcast instance we connect to a remote instance that is already running. We pass in a config with all the same serializers we used before. We successfully connect to Hazelcast and we can put stuff in the map (works as far as I can tell) but we don't get anything back out. No events get fired letting our listeners know objects were added to a map.

I want to be able to connect to a Hazelcast instance that is already running outside of our JVM. It is not working for our use case and I am not sure how it is supposed to work.

1. Does the JVM running Hazelcast externally need in its class loader all of the class types we might put into the map? It seems like that might be where the problem is but wouldn't that make it very limiting to use Hazelcast?
2. How do you typically manage those class loader issues?
3. Assuming the above is true, is there a way to tell Hazelcast we will serialize the objects before even putting them in the map? Basically we would give Hazelcast an ID and byte array and that is all we would expect back in return. If so that would avoid the entire class loader issue I think we are running into. We do not need to be able to search on objects based on their fields. We just need to know as objects come and go and what their ID is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jonathan, when using client-server architecture, unless you use queries or other operations that require data to be serialized on the cluster, members don't need to know anything about serialization. They just store already serialized data & serve it. If these listeners that you mentioned are on the client app, it should be working fine.

Hazelcast has a feature called User Code Deployment, https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#member-user-code-deployment-beta, but it's mainly for user classes. Serialization related config should be present on members or you should add that later & do a rolling restart.

If you can share some of the exceptions/setup etc, I can give specific answers as well.

Comment: Based on your answer I don't have to worry about serializers at the server. We are using Kubernetes and OSGi in our solution. We went back, cleaned everything up, recompiled, created new containers, and reran our test. This time the client worked without issue, all without any code changes. So you are correct, a client can create their own custom serializers that the server need not be bothered with. In our case, all our clients will have those exact same serialized registered before any operations take place so I think we are good to go.

Comment: good. Please note that other than cache put/get, if you use queries or Entry Processors etc. then members need to know how to deserialize the data.